# Facebook Post Embed with comments

Tags: facebook, embed, posts

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="Div1"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=618680391516953";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<fb:post href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553" width="500"></fb:post>
```

So the above code will embed a post on to my website but now I also want to show the comments of the post and if possible be able to add comments directly.

Is this possible or does anyone have any example VB code for doing this with Facebook SDK?

Thanks